# Achieve slide effect when app loads in Panorama Application for WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

does anyone know how to achieve the page sliding effect that happens when a panorama app opens its first page?

The effect just simply slides the page to the left as it opens.

Some examples I've seen are the Facebook app and the PhotoStudio app by Samsung.

It looks like this animation works fine when an application is being reactivated, but just not when someone is opening it normally. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not set the Panorama in your first page. Use a dummy loading page and navigate from it to the panorama page to achieve this effect. I'm not sure if this is wanted behavior, it is what it is :)

Answer (score 0):

The only clue to this that I've seen is that the documents do hint that something "special" should happen when coming out of tombstoning:

> However, if you need to set the default section when returning from a tombstoned state, you can use the Panorama.DefaultItem property.

from http://phone.codeplex.com/documentation

But really I'm not sure why or how the panorama detects that it hasn't been navigated back to!

Comment: Sorry - meant to post that as a comment - not as an answer - sorry!

Comment: Also, if you are trying to "fit in" with other applications then you shouldn't try to deliberately add this effect.

Comment: But if you do want to create your own panorama, try http://blogs.codes-sources.com/kookiz/archive/2010/03/23/wp7-create-a-panoramic-view-using-silverlight.aspx

Comment: The strange thing is though, that this animation happens when the app comes back from tombstoning. It just doesn't happen when you load open the app normally.